# Order by must be called before calling a skip

Tags: c#, linq, skip

I'm getting an Error when trying to execute the skip method. The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

I'm well aware that the orderby must be called prior to calling the skip and I am calling it prior to the skip in another function directly preceding the call.

```
AddOrderBy(AdvTitleResults, ColumnNumber, OrderByDesc);

var SearchTitles = AdvTitleResults.Skip(PageNum * NumberOfResults)
                                  .Take(NumberOfResults).ToList();
```

The order by function looks like this the default assures that it is always assigned:

```
private void AddOrderBy(IQueryable<Title> Results, int ColumnNumber, bool OrderByDesc)
{
    switch (ColumnNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.FK_ContentType);
           else
                Results = Results.OrderBy(t => t.FK_ContentType);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.TitleFullName);
            else
                Results = Results.OrderBy(t => t.TitleFullName);
            break;
        default:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID);
            else
                Results = Results.OrderBy(t => t.ID);
            break;
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not actually changing the `AdvTitleResults`, you are changing the value of your parameter. You need to use `ref` keyword to make it work:

```
AddOrderBy(ref AvTitleResults, ColumnNumber, OrderByDesc);

private void AddOrderBy(ref IQueryable<Title> Results, 
                        int ColumnNumber, 
                        bool OrderByDesc)
```

Or you can use the LINQ style and make it an extension method, and return the query:

```
private IOrderedQueryable<Title> AddOrderBy(this IQueryable<Title> Results, int ColumnNumber, bool OrderByDesc)
{
    switch (ColumnNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                return Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.FK_ContentType);
           else
                return Results.OrderBy(t => t.FK_ContentType);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                return Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.TitleFullName);
            else
                return Results.OrderBy(t => t.TitleFullName);
            break;
        default:
            if (OrderByDesc)
                return Results.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID);
            else
                return Results.OrderBy(t => t.ID);
            break;
    }
}
```

This way you can call it like any other LINQ method:

```
var SearchTitles = AdvTitleResults
      .AddOrderBy(ColumnNumber, OrderByDesc)
      .Skip(PageNum * NumberOfResults)
      .Take(NumberOfResults)
      .ToList();
```

---

**Edit:**

> isn't IQueryable a class shouldn't this be pass by ref by default?

`IQueryable<Title>` is not a class but yes it's a reference type. But reference types are not *actually* passed by reference.When you pass a referece type, the reference value that your variable holds will be **copied** into a new variable.It's something like this:

```
string foo = "Foo";
string bar = foo; // copy foo's reference into bar
```

Now if you assign a new reference to `bar` it won't change the `foo`:

```
bar = "bar";
```

Because they are distinct variables that holds a reference to same address.But when you use `ref` keyword the reference value is not copied.Instead you can think like the variable itself is passed.That's the easiest way to understand that. I don't know how to reproduce this behaviour in C# syntax.

Comment: He should really be returning the new query, not using `ref`.

Comment: isn't IQueryable<Title> a class shouldn't this be pass by ref by default?

Comment: @Space All parameters are always passed by value unless the `ref` keyword is used.  All parameters are passed by reference when the `ref` keyword *is* used.

Comment: @Servy if you pass a list into a void function and call .add on the list when you return isn't the list going to have the data in it that you added?

Comment: @Space It sure is.  That doesn't change the fact that you passed the reference to the list by value, and not by reference.

Comment: @Space Yes, it will, because the value that got passed in was a reference to a list, not a reference to a variable (which holds a reference to a list).  You can modify the list, but you can't modify a variable pointing to that list (unless you use `ref`).

Comment: @Servy that makes sense now, that detail always through me off, so that's why when you pass a list into a void function and assign it to a new list when you return it's still assigned to the old list, because the new list create a new reference and it then is dissasociated with the old reference. Thanks this makes more sense now

Comment: @Space using a member of type and assigning a new reference are different things. I have added an explanation about ref's behaviour I hope that will be helpful